# Install 16.04 as main OS - UEFI mode

Tags: 16.04, uefi

I'd like some feedback if possible as I'm not an expert on this. I'd like to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTs on my desktop as the main OS (no dual boot etc). My motherboard is [MSI 970 Gaming](https://www.anandtech.com/show/8907/msi-970-gaming-motherboard-review-undercutting-am3-at-100/2).

In order to do the installation do I need to disable Fast boot (screenshot 1) and UEFI mode (screenshot 2) - the Boot mode select in my case says Legacy UEFI so I'm not sure whats the difference from UEFI?

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: You should disable all the fast boot and windows 8 features, and should enable secure boot and disable legacy boot support (boot mode should be UEFI only, not Legacy+UEFI). If you are installing to NVMe, you also need to make sure you have updated BIOS flashed which correctly supports it, first.

Comment: What do you mean by NVMe? Not sure I understand

Comment: @dobey - fast boot is different from Window's fast startup. it does not need to be disabled.

Comment: @lykos an M.2 NVMe SSD I mean. It may need updated firmware to boot correctly

Comment: You should consider keeping Windows for updating drivers/bios/firmware. It's also good to have a working Windows dual boot system if Ubuntu breaks for some reason. You can shrink the size of Windows C:\ to a bare minimum of 25GB or 40GB or whatever. As for NVMe M.2 SSD drivers I found once they were updated in Windows (along with all the other drivers needing updating) I had no problem installing and booting Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Do I also need to format my hard drive to NTFS or FAT32? I'm having a Samsung SSD 250GB 2.5 inch (not sure if this is what @dobey was referring to)

Comment: You don't need to keep Windows (assuming you have a license and don't want to keep Windows). SATA 2.5 SSDs are not what I was referring to. You don't need to format the disk as NTFS/FAT either. The Ubuntu installer will format the disk appropriately.